# custom gradle download task with Basic Authorisation fails

Tags: gradle, jenkins, build.gradle, gradlew

In our Jenkins pipeline, we use some gradle scripts. The current script, performs a rest API call and collects the response to a json file.

Jenkins :

```
node('windows_node') {
    def gitlabTokenList = CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(GitLabApiTokenImpl.class)
    def creds = gitlabTokenList.findResult { it.id == "API_TOKEN" ? it : null }
    def gitlabToken = creds.apiToken
    def concatGitlabToken = ':'+creds.apiToken
    def encoded_token = concatGitlabToken.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
    println "encoded_token: "+encoded_token


    try {

        stage('Prepare Workspace') {
            cleanWs()
            checkout scm
            bat label: 'update Json', script: "gradlew.bat  updateLibJson -PgitAccessToken=${encoded_token} --stacktrace"
        }
}
```

On the build.gradle, we define the download plugin and the task as follows :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://XXXX.XX.XX/repositories/gradle-plugins-release/'
        }
        maven {
            url 'http://XXXX.XX.XX/repository/gradle-plugins/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
            classpath 'de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'de.undercouch.download'

task updateLibJson(type: Download) {
    group "Prepare"
    src 'https://XXX/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.0'
    dest 'lib_repos.json'
    header  'Authorization: Basic ', gitAccessToken
    println "after updateLibJsonn"
}
```

I have done the API testing using Insomnia, and I get a 200 response. However, from the jenkins side I get a 401 response saying that the src URL cannot be accessed.

Any suggestions?